# windows socket(ipv6) cannot receive Neighbor Advertisement(NA) packet

Tags: sockets, ipv6, icmp

I used a Raw Socket(IPv6) to send/receive ICMP packets.  It works fine to send ping request(type 128) and receive ping receive(type 129) packets.  And it also works well to send Neighbor Solicitation(type 135).

But the same socket always cannot receive the Neighbor Advertisement(NA) packet.
I'm not sure is there any socket opts should be set in my case?
Thanks for help.

after set "RCVALL_ON" to socket, the NA packet can be recieved from socket. Is this means that the NA packet only can be received in this way?

Comment: You could also try limiting it to "RCVALL_IPLEVEL", since NAs are addressed to all-nodes multicast or your unicast address. The host should be listening to both.

Comment: if the NA packet send to my unicast address, I still need to set "RCVALL_IPLEVEL"?

Comment: I dont know. Maybe you can try it, since you mentioned already successfully sending NS messages. Send an NS from the host where your code is running and see if the code captures the reply.

Comment: Would you care to show some actual code?